# ¿Como eliminar un archivo concreto dentro de una carpeta en un bucket de s3 Amazon con Laravel 7?

Tags: laravel-7, amazon-s3

tengo que poder eliminar un archivo concreto de dentro de una carpeta concreta en un bucket en s3 Amazon con Laravel 7, y no tengo forma, encontré este ejemplo pero me elimina toda la carpeta, con todos los archivos que hay dentro:

```
 $files = Storage::disk('s3')->files('test/');

        Storage::disk('s3')->delete($files);
```

Necesito ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Lo logré:

```
        $file = 'test1.txt';
        $files_in_path = Storage::disk('s3')->files('test');
        
        Storage::disk('s3')->delete('test/'.$file);
```

Le marco el archivo dentro del path que quiero borrar.